# Secure email client for Android

Tags: gratis, android, email-client

Related question : [Secure email client for Windows and Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50658/secure-email-client-for-windows-and-android) - this time, I will settle for an Android only solution.

Until/unless I get an answer to my question [K9 not showing all mails in unified inbox](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219146/k9-not-showing-all-mails-in-unified-inbox), I am searching for a new Android email client. I am perfectly happy with K9 (except for that quite major problem), so something similar would be welcome.

I need something which :

- will handle multiple accounts (at least a dozen), and keep them separate (although a unified inbox is also nice)
- has good search capabilities (message body too, not just header) partial sender address, wildcard searches, date range searches, all of these combinable
- a bunch of plugins would be nice
- I especially want GPG support
- and I don't want it scanning my emails & using me as "the product"
- has IMAP support
- allows me to schedule how often it checks for new mail (not once an hour, like Gmail)
- supports common mailbox formats, so that I could switch to a new client & import
- tags are nice
- mark as "in need of reply" & remind me
- it would be nice to be able to download all of my email to SD card (given how large they are nowadays), so that I can view/search them all while  offline

I don't need a calendar or fancy address book, but won't object. Low resource usage would be nice. Stable, with good support & an active user community.

Gratis (and add-free) would be great, but I am willing to pay, if there is a compelling reason. I don't need open source, but don't object to it.

It is ***very important*** to me that the client not be tied with a service, especially not one which stores my email or login details on its own server - my login details should be sent only from my Android device to the mail server, and my email should not be read/scanned by any intermediaries.

Comment: Not checked it myself, but did you take a look at Marcel's FairEmail (available at F-Droid)? Marcel is the one who also wrote XPrivacy, so he's got a focus on that part. From what I've heard, FairEmail should be much more intuitive and convenient to use than k9. And it's definitely maintained: Marcel's release frequency is that high that F-Droid cannot keep up (and I was asked to mirror his APKs *LOL* )…

Comment: Thanks, Izzy, sounds great. I am working my way through [free Android alternatives to K9 mail](https://alternativeto.net/software/k-9/?license=free&platform=android)  but will break off & check out FairMail